# How to use F1-F12 keys with MacBook?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

Blender requires F-keys such as <kbd>F12</kbd> and numpad. The numpad emulation works for me, but I am unable to get the function keys such as <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> working. For example, <kbd>F12</kbd> should do rendering. So how can I use Blender with a MacBook?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have two options; either hold down <kbd>fn</kbd> as L2G suggested, or switch to the <kbd>F1</kbd> etc. keys to work like that directly.

This can be setup in keyboard preferences here:

[image]

If you do that, <kbd>F1</kbd> will work as the actual <kbd>F1</kbd> key. If you want to use it for controlling the brightness, you'd hit <kbd>fn</kbd> with it.

Comment: You just need to remove the shortcuts to Fuction keys from the Keyboard Shortcuts menu. Otherwise F12 is not rendering but dashboard.

Answer (score 7):

To clarify and expand on HHH's comments: in at least some recent versions of OS X, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, and <kbd>F12</kbd> are set by default as shortcuts to control Expose, Spaces, and Dashboard. Houbysoft's and L2G's solutions don't work in this case; holding <kbd>fn</kbd> activates Expose/etc, and checking "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" in System Preferences/Keyboard just means you get Expose from the unmodified function key instead of from <kbd>fn</kbd> + function key.

The solution is: in System Preferences/Keyboard, open the Keyboard Shortcuts tab, and find and uncheck the relevant shortcuts.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @Robert's solution (which in turn expands on @houbysoft's solution), to get <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> to execute application-specific functions (such as using <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the developer tools in Chrome), you'll need to:

1. Execute @houbysoft's solution
2. Open System Preferences
3. Go to Keyboard
4. Go to Shortcuts
5. Click on Mission Control
6. Uncheck "Show Desktop" and "Show Dashboard"

[image: Screenshot showing what to uncheck]

Answer (score 4):

You need to hold down the <kbd>fn</kbd> key (lower-left corner) while you're typing one of the <kbd>F1</kbd>–<kbd>F12</kbd> keys. This is the norm for any app that uses F-keys, not just Blender.

Comment: This does not work for me. When I press this either with houbysoft's suggestion or not, I get the expose screen with a lot of little apps?! EDIT I got it working after disabling the shortcuts in the settings of the houbysoft, thank you.